# Sending Push Notifications to Firebase Users in AngularJS app (no server code)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I have an AngularJS app with no server code. I created a form in which I'd like to be able to type a message and send as a push notification to all Firebase users using our mobile app. I've looked at Firebase Cloud Messaging and services such as OneSignal, however, both strongly advise against sending push notifications via client for security reasons.

Has anyone been able do something like this? Any suggestions are appreciated. I'm not attached to any method besides the ones that work well and securely.

Thank you.

Comment: You can totally do it, it's just that in doing so you'll be exposing your private key, which means anyone could send notifications on your behalf. So you should't do it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539133/send-firebase-cloud-message-from-client-without-exposing-api-secret

Comment: If you're asking how to send device-to-device messages with Firebase Cloud Messaging, that has been asked before as Jaime points out. If you're asking for recommendations on a service that *does* allow sending device-to-device messages, such recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow. I recommend reading: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Comment: I'd like to know specifically about securely sending messages from a web client to a device. I saw some of the device-to-device questions, but my knowledge on iOS and Android programming is very limited, and I'm operating under the assumption that theres server code there.